# How to understand such where-in clause as where col01 in (true)?

Tags: mysql, where-in

Suppose there is a table called `tab01` and it has a column called `col01` in `varchar` type. And statements are shown below.

```
# the first statement
SELECT * FROM tab01 WHERE col01 IN (TRUE);
# the second statement
SELECT * FROM tab01 WHERE col01 IN (FALSE);
# the third statement
SELECT * FROM tab01 WHERE col01 IN ('val01');
```

From [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html), these three statements have the form of `bit_expr [NOT] IN (expr [, expr] ...)`. In my intuition, the row should be returned as long as the `expr` is evaluated to `True`.

Why does the first statement return nothing? In my view, the first statement, `SELECT * FROM tab01 WHERE col01 IN (TRUE);`, should return all records and the second statement, `SELECT * FROM tab01 WHERE col01 IN (FALSE);` should return nothing. I cannot find any clues in this [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html).

Comment: What is the datatype of COL01 and what possible values exist in that column?

Comment: Please share the table structure and some sample data such that others can reproduce your problem

Comment: If you don't understand rewrite it to be understandable..

Comment: @SalmanA The data type of `col01` is string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql `TRUE` is equal to `1` and `FALSE` is equal to `0`.
So the 1st statement is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM tab01 WHERE col01 IN (1);
```

and unless the column `col01` contains values equal to `1` (or starting with `1` and then contain non numeric characters), you will get nothing returned.
The 2nd statement is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM tab01 WHERE col01 IN (0);
```

and it *would* also return nothing if the column `col01` does not contain values equal to `0`, **but** in this case, as it is explained in [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) of the documenatation, there are other factors to consider.
Say that the column's `col01` data type is `varchar`, the comparison:

```
col01 IN (0)
```

will do an implicit conversion of `col01` to `INTEGER` and unless the value of `col01` starts with numeric characters, the result of this conversion will always be `0` and so the result of the comparison will be `TRUE`.
So your 2nd statement will return normally all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, `TRUE` evaluates as `1`. So the first query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM tab01 WHERE col01 = 1;
```

And the second statement means:

```
SELECT * FROM tab01 WHERE col01 = 0;
```

If `col01` is not numeric, MySQL will do conversion before comparison. This can lead to suprising results when the numeric value being compared is `0` (typically: `'a' = 0` is true).